# TFLearn example code gives invalid placeholder error

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

The code for a Convolutional Neural Network using TFLearn at https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py does not work.

When run, it gives an error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'TargetsData/Y' with dtype float and shape [?]

I have the same problem when running other TFLearn examples. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The code example worked fine for me using tflearn version 0.3.2.

But, I reproduced the same error when re-running the code without restarting the kernel of a Jupyter notebook or reseting the default graph.

Insert the following lines of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

## Building Convolutional Network
# ...
```